# Hadoop Map-Reduce , Need to combine two mapper with one common Reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce, mapper

I need to implement below Functionality using Hadoop Map-Reduce?

1) I am reading one input for a mapper from one source & another input from another different input source.

2) I need to pass both output of mapper into a single reducer for further process.

Is there any to do the above requirement in Hadoop Map-Reduce

Comment: If your mappers output the same type data, you can use `MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, path, inputFormatClass,
                    mapperClass);` to add multiple mappers.

Comment: ya thanks for the info,  but i need to add two different outputs of mapper for a single reducer? How can i achieve this??

Comment: I usually convert all the different types of value to BytesWritable, and recovery them to the actual value in the reducer. Also a tag needs to be attached, so that the reducer can know how to recovery the values.

Comment: @zsxwing +1 Yes this is the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MultipleInputs.addInputPath` is what you are looking for. This is how your configuration would look like. Make sure both AnyMapper1 and AnyMapper2 write the same output expected by MergeReducer

```
JobConf conf = new JobConf(Merge.class);
conf.setJobName("merge");

conf.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class); 
conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class); 
conf.setReducerClass(MergeReducer.class);
conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf, inputDir1, SequenceFileInputFormat.class, AnyMapper1.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf, inputDir2, TextInputFormat.class, AnyMapper2.class);

FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, outputPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom writable. You can populate the same in the Mapper. Later in the Reducer you can get the Custom writable Object and do the necessary business operation.